# Type () does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know the reason but I can't check if an UIImage is `nil` that is the code

```
        var arrayBuildingImage: [UIImage] = []

        for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++){

            var path:String = self.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("building/\(i).png")

            if ( arrayBuildingImage[i] = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)? ) {//ERROR HERE

            }
            else{
                break
            }

        }
```

Error:

**Type () does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'**

I'm using Swift 1.1

Comment: Why do you use Swift 1.1 instead of Swift 2?

Comment: are you sure you aren't typo in your `arrayBuildingImage[i] = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)?`. You don't mean `arrayBuildingImage[i] == UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)?` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        arrayBuildingImage[i] = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)?
        if ( arrayBuildingImage[i] != nil ) {//ERROR HERE

        }
        else{
            break
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if it's nil:

```
let img : UIImage? = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
if img != nil {}
```

or use the "if let" statement:

```
if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {}
```

and in a more "Swifty" way:

```
guard let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) else { return }
// Do you stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Swift.

In Swift, the operand of an "if" statement must be a Boolean expression. An assignment operator produces no value (or a value of type Void, if you prefer).

Either compare the result of the assignment with nil, or much better use "if let".